# How do I pass a parameter to a dropdownlist in Kendo UI which uses an MVVM object

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a simple dropdown list that I'm attaching a viewModel to though the observable method.

```
<input class="span-full" data-role="dropdownlist" id="DROPDOWNONE" data-bind="events: {open: getProps }, value: '+ __cols[n].name +' ">
```

I'm binding it to an open function like so:

```
    var viewModel = new kendo.observable({
        boolValues: ['','true','false'],
        sortFields1:  _sortFields,
        sortFields2:  _sortFields,

        getProps: function(e){
            console.log(e.sender);
        }
    });
```

What I want to do is when a user opens the menu with their mouse is to have the value of the id passed to it. Like so.

```
getProps: function(e){

    // Code I'm missing goes here.
    // var id = grabsomething.fromsomeplace();
   console.log(id); // Outputs DROPDOWNONE
}
```

Comment: just use bind event instead of open

Comment: Okay, I thought that was what I was doing. Can you give me and example?

Comment: check this out http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/mvvm

Comment: and  this http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-parameter-to-grid-datasource

Comment: Ha, that's exactly where I got the code I am working with. I must be missing something. I'm already binding the open function to the widget. What I'm trying to do is find out what element was clicked. It needs to be dynamic.

Comment: update the question and if you can provide some running sample even not working we might be able to figure out what is going on

Comment: Okay, here you go. Like I said I just need to find out that the id, or value of any of the attributes are from the menu is when a user opens it. The reason being is that will determine the call I make to the back end to populate the drop down menu.